# Пытаюсь отправить данные на сервер и получаю null, хотя запрос сформирован верно. В чем причина?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, null

У меня есть кнопка по активации которой улетают данные POST запросом на сервер.

**Так я вызываю метод**

```
     <v-button
          class="button-recomended "
          @upGetStatisctics="SendOrderMar"
        >
```

**Вот мой метод, в котором я собираю данные:**

```
SendOrderMar() {
  const body_margins = {
    order_json: {
      table: this.margins,
      client_id: this.$store.state.calculator.users,
    },
  };
  console.log("MARGINS", this.margins);
  console.log("store-SendOrderMar", this.$store.state);
  console.log(
    "$store.state.calculator.users",
    this.$store.state.calculator.users
  );
  console.log("BODY", body_margins);
  this.sendOrderMargins(body_margins);
  this.isEditing = false;
},
```

**Далее в store я отправляю их:**

```
async sendOrderMargins({ commit }, data) {
  const url = "admin/margins";
  console.log("admin/margins",data);
  axios.post(url, data);

},
```

**Вот, что я получаю по логам:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Тут все верно, улетает юзер и таблица с данными, но когда я смотрю в кладку network, то вижу null**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**В чем может быть причина ???**

Comment: А что не видно именно? Я добавил кнопку чтобы было понятно, что я вызываю этот метод. Далее в методе в переменную я складываю все данные и передаю эту переменную в sendOrderMargins, а в store уже в data есть все эти параметры, я по логам смотрел. Что именно не так ?

Comment: Вы во кладке network смотрите ответ от АПИ. Может, это вопрос к АПИ?